# Thymleaf th:each iteration not showing working and not showing data

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, spring-thymeleaf

Thymleaf th:each iteration not showing working and not showing data

'

```
    <tr style="background-color: black; color: white">
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Total Cases</th>
    </tr>

    <tr th:each="data : ${stats}">
        <td th:text="${data.country}"></td>
        <td th:text="${data.state}"></td>
        <td th:text="${data.latestTotalCases}">0</td>
    </tr>
```

'

Comment: Hi. Are you sure that `stats` attribute is added to the model?

Comment: yes check this..

Comment: '@Controller
public class HomeController {

 @Autowired
 CoronaVirusDataService coronaVirusDataService;

 @GetMapping("/")
 public String Home(Model model) {

  model.addAttribute("stats", coronaVirusDataService.getAllStats());

  return "home";

 }

}         
'

Comment: but this is working

Comment: <tr th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 5)}" th:value="${i}">
   <td th:text="'No.' + ${i}"></td>
  </tr>

Comment: I guess you need to reproduce your issue with minimal code and post it for us. It could be playground or some repository we can take a look at. "Not working" with this amount of code doesn't give any info for us.

Comment: Try using th:if to conditionally render the table based on whether the stats model attribute is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

As per guide use **th:block**

```
<th:block th:each="data : ${stats}">
    <tr>
        <td th:text="${data.country}"></td>
        <td th:text="${data.state}"></td>
        <td th:text="${data.latestTotalCases}">0</td>
    </tr>
</th:block>
```